# Using Gson For Json Post in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Following a tutorial which I didn't fully understand I did the following:

I created four classes.

```
        package com.example.android.wearable.watchface;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class Beansubject {

            @SerializedName("subject")
            private static String subject;
            @SerializedName("price")
            private static String price;
            @SerializedName("author")
            private static String author;
            @SerializedName("topics")
            private static ArrayList<BeanTopic> beanTopics;

            public Beansubject(ArrayList<BeanTopic> beanTopics, String subject, String price, String author) {
                this.beanTopics = beanTopics;
                this.subject = subject;
                this.price = price;
                this.author = author;
            }

            public static String getSubject() {
                return subject;
            }
            public static void setSubject(String subj) {
               subject = subj;
            }
            public static String getPrice() {
                return price;
            }
            public static void setPrice(String pric) {
                price = pric;
            }
            public String getAuthor() {
                return author;
            }
            public static void setAuthor(String aue) {
            author = aue;
            }
            public static ArrayList<BeanTopic> getBeanTopics() {
                return beanTopics;
            }
            public static void setBeanTopics(ArrayList<BeanTopic> beantcs) {
                beanTopics = beantcs;
            }
        }
```

Next

```
            package com.example.android.wearable.watchface;
            import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
            public class BeanTopic {

                @SerializedName("title")
                private String title;

                public BeanTopic(String title) {
                    this.title = title;
                }

                public String getTitle() {
                    return title;
                }
                public void setTitle(String title) {
                    this.title = title;
                }
            }
```

Next

```
        package com.example.android.wearable.watchface;
        import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
        import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.Reader;
        public class API {
            private static Reader reader=null;
            public static Reader getData(String SERVER_URL) {
                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                        reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
                    } else {
        //   Log.e("error:", "Server responded with status code: "+ statusLine.getStatusCode());
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return reader;
            }
        }
```

Finally

```
    package com.example.android.wearable.watchface;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        TextView txtSubject;
        TextView txtAuthor;
        TextView txtPrice;
        TextView txtTopicsList;
        Beansubject beanSubject;
        StringBuffer topicList;

        public void Json() {

            new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    Reader reader=API.getData("http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/OkS85Le");
                    beanSubject = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(reader, Beansubject.class);
                    Log.e("Subject: ", beanSubject.getSubject() + "");
                    Log.e("Author: ", beanSubject.getAuthor() + "");
                    Log.e("Price: ", beanSubject.getPrice() + "");
                    ArrayList<BeanTopic> topicArrayList = beanSubject.getBeanTopics();
                    topicList = new StringBuffer();
                    for(BeanTopic topic: topicArrayList){
                        Log.e("topic title: ",topic.getTitle()+"");
                        topicList.append("* " + topic.getTitle()+"\n");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    txtSubject.setText("Subject: " + beanSubject.getSubject());
                    txtPrice.setText("price: "+beanSubject.getPrice());
                    txtAuthor.setText("Author: "+beanSubject.getAuthor());
                    txtTopicsList.setText("Topics: "+"\n" + topicList);
                }
            }.execute();

        }

    }
```

The error is that I'm not sure how to create the objects that are in the tutorial in the last part for the activity class.
For the parts I did not understand in this last part of the tutorial where objects are being created which are possibly linked and possibly not to other classes I took random guesses for what they are.
 I even made some stuff static in the other classes and removed "this." to get something to work. Please help me understand that last part of the tutorial so I could understand fully how to do this simple task. Thanks.

Here is the link to this simple tutorial:
http://www.nkdroid.com/2014/11/json-object-parsing-using-url-in-android.html

Okay, so these are my unknown variables: MyActivity.this, progressdialog, txtpostlist, postlist, beanpostarraylist. I am using a different tutorial now -> more basic. So I'm not sure why the tutorial is so vague with creating the MainActivity Class. What is missing? http://nkdroid.com/2014/11/json-parsing-using-gson-in-android.html

Comment: _Please help me fix this code!_ You haven't told us how it is broken.

Comment: The error is quite simple, it is just those objects (of Activity class) that I do not understand how to create them because the tutorial is vague on that last Activity Class part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May help to look at the data being provided by API call.

paste result belo to  http://json.parser.online.fr/

curl -v http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/OkS85Le

```
{"topics": [{"title": "how to add fontawesome icons in android example"},
            {"title": "how to parse json parsing using gson library"},
            {"title": "how to store arraylist in sharedpreferences"}],
 "auther": "nirav kalola",
 "price": "free",
 "subject": "Android Application Development Tutorial"}
```

So , the 3 "title" elements in the JSON wind up in UI because of the following :

```
beanSubject = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(reader, Beansubject.class);

ArrayList<BeanTopic> topicArrayList = beanSubject.getBeanTopics();

for(BeanTopic topic: topicArrayList){
                    topicList.append("* " + topic.getTitle()+"\n");
                }

txtTopicsList.setText("Topics: "+"\n" + topicList);
```

code gets data

MVC model/collection objs created from JSON Array

UI list set from collection obj

[see here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) for more on Adapters getting data from the collection Object holders.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a layout that have some TextView components with the corresping ids. So create one xml file with some textviews with the proper ids. Then override the onCreate method, and call the JSON method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.id.my_layout);
    txtSubject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);
    ...
    Json();
}
```

If something is unclear, I recommend you to read a basic android tutorial (the one from the official site is great).

Comment: I'm not very good at this. What kind of XML file is to be created (there are several)? And finally how do I create the TextViews?

Comment: @Newton Check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html This is well explained and very fast

Comment: It makes sense to me. However, as I'm editing a watch face the XMLs under layout are not text editable, I see a picture of a phone with other things there.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant.

Comment: Never mind I found a place to edit text there, I just hope it works the same way as anywhere.

Comment: Okay, so these are my unknown variables:  MyActivity.this,
            progressdialog,
            txtpostlist,
             postlist,
            beanpostarraylist. I am not sure that an XML file will solve that and I am using a different tutorial now -> more basic. So I'm not sure why the tutorial is so vague with creating the MainActivity Class. What is missing? http://www.nkdroid.com/2014/11/json-parsing-using-gson-in-android.html

Comment: @Newton Is there the all project you can download the sources. I mean what you need is to setup a basic xml layout with some textviews. Take a look at this: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/textview/android-textview-example/